# Four different greek words roughly translated as 'With' - I'm missing one?

Tags: ancient-greek

I'm not knowledgeable on ancient greek.

I was listening to someone who said in passing that ancient greek has (at least) four different words roughly translated as the English word "With".

To sate my curiosity, I was looking up their definitions, but I can't find the fourth word the speaker was referring to.

The three I've already found are:

1. **para** : familiar to me as "alongside", like "parachute"
2. **pros** : "besides, over and above, thereto, in addition" / "at (a place), toward (a person or place)"

It seems 'pros' may also mean, "in front of" / "before" (and in, "standing before")?
The person I heard talking, mentioned it may also have a more intimate implications, like face-to-face / staring in the eyes, and being uncovered / exposed / seen? <strike>Could you elaborate on any nuance like this?</strike>
**Edit:** [Found a reference for that](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CF%81%CF%8C%CF%82#Ancient_Greek). 'pros' can mean, apparently, "*at the side of, pertaining to, at the hand of, before, next to, in the presence of, in the eyes of, in the sight of, in the name of*"

3. **syn** (['syn-'](https://membean.com/roots/syn-together/) as in 'synthesis' or 'synonym', "with/together/")

The one I can't find, I am almost certainly misspelling, since I heard it audibly only:

4. **matta / matar** ("muh-ta")

I found [this word 'matta'](https://www.bibletools.org/index.cfm/fuseaction/Lexicon.show/ID/H4302/matta%60.htm), but doesn't seem to be a word meaning "with", and instead seems to be about planting plants in gardens.

Does anyone know what this remaining greek word I'm misspelling may be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just to tack on to what Draconis said, [**μετά**](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dmeta%2F) (similarly pronounced to the English "meta", but with a proper dental instead of a flap) can indeed mean "with" when it's used with a genitive, which you can find under section A.II in the above link.

You'll also see it spell **μετ᾽** (pronounced like "met") before a unaspirated vowel and **μεθ᾽** (<met<sup>h</sup>>) before an aspirated vowel.

The word is likely cognate with words like the English *amidst*, German *mit*, and Latin *medius*, though precisely how is a matter of debate.

*Matta*, on the other hand, isn't Greek. You're looking at a website that combined Greek and Hebrew words. The word you found is actually the Hebrew [*מַטָּע*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A2), which means "plantation." It's a completely unrelated word from the other words.

Answer (score 7):

I'm guessing the missing word was **μετά** (*metá*), which can mean "in the midst of", "by the aid of", "after", and many other things. (Greek prepositions are complicated!)

Comment: Thank you so much, I bet you are correct that this was what he said!